# How to put a Magento CE website into maintenance mode?

Tags: magento, maintenance-mode

Where do I add the file name:  maintenance.flag
in order to put my website into maintenance mode?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related. You should post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 3):

You drop a file name `maintenance.flag` directly in the root folder of your magento system, along side `index.php`, and Magento should put your system in maintenance mode.